# Inline JavaScript to separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

How would you add this to a separate JavaScript file? I started with this but it seems not to work. The console error is Uncaught ReferenceError: isNumberKey is not defined.

```
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);>

function isNumberKey(event) {
    return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : 
    event.charCode >= 48 && 
    event.charCode <= 57;
}
```

```html
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Comment: The error means that the function is not defined, make sure you're including the JS script file in your code.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I'm using this to get javascript file <script src="@Html.Raw(Html.GetHashName("incomeHistory.*.js"))"></script>

Comment: if you're loading the page and checking the developers tools -> network tab. Do you actually see the js file being loaded? If not, it's not a JS problem rather ASP problem.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Its their. I set a breakpoint and its near hit. It can't even read the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the function inside of a `script` tag? Your code works for me when I do so (you were also missing a closing parenthisis with the `onkeypress` event)

```html
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"/>
<script>
function isNumberKey(event) {
    return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : 
    event.charCode >= 48 && 
    event.charCode <= 57;
}
</script>
```

Edit: to place in a separate file you'd want to add a `script` tag with a `src`, like this:

```
<script src="my-js-file-name.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, but your ternary operator wasn't doing anything other than returning null or boolean, so nothing noticeable was happening. Look what happens when you assign the ternary to a variable and console log it:

```js
function isNumberKey(e) 
{
  const res = (e.charCode == 8 || e.charCode == 0) ? null : e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57
  console.log(res)
}
```

```html
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="isNumberKey(event);">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to put inside a external javascript, just copy the code, without the `<script>` tag and put, in the html, the `<script src="myfile.js" />`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by simply doing this. Not sure why .NET was freaking out about how I was calling it with using WebPack.

```js
const Test = document.getElementById("Test");
Test.onkeypress = isNumberKey;

// Prevent pasting (since pasted content might include non-number characters)
Test.onpaste = event => false;

function isNumberKey(event) {
    return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
}
```

```html
<input min='0' id="Test" type="number" onkeypress="isNumberKey();>
```